# Any way to raise a dialog similar to `z=`?

Tags: vim-windows

`z=` on misspelled words shows a dialog (set spelling before). Can I get the dialog by a function?

Comment: I know about the confirm function

Comment: you can build your own dialogs by using popup windows.

Comment: You mean `:h inputlist()`?

Comment: Yes, Matt. Thanks